# Including libraries distributed as class files in ant script

Tags: class, ant, java

I'm currently trying to compile a project using ant which uses a number of external libraries (specifically apache.hwpf, and JDom2) distributed as .class files.

I'm currently using eclipse to edit and build the project, but I'd like to switch over to using an ant file, as it should be eaiser to maintain (don't need a specific version of eclipse), and eaiser to build (just run "ant build" or something.

The problem is, I'm not sure where I should be including the libraries in the ant file. My current ant file (see below) always fails at the javac stage, so I think it should be there. It generally because it can't find things like "Element", which is a class defined by the JDom2 library.

Could somebody explain where I should be importing it, and how.

(EDIT: As an addendum, the functionality i'm trying to get is similar to adding a class folder under the libraries tab of build path in project properties in eclipse. This works currently for building my project, but I'd like to move away from eclipse if possible.)

(EDIT: further clarification; what I'd do in eclipse by doing Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Class Folder, I'd like to be able to do using ant.)

My ant script so far is:

```
<project>
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class" value="ba_cc.Main"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/Change_Checker.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/Change_Checker.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,compile,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Eclipse is not too friendly when it comes too fully custom Ant builds. I am just recommending to use NetBeans (which has 100% integration with Ant), if you really want to control all parts of the building process.

Comment: I'm trying to shift away from using eclipse partly because of this - I'm aiming for a fully seperate process using Ant if possible.

Comment: Yeah, if that's the case, using NetBeans will save you a lot of time. But be sure that NetBeans have all features you used in Eclipse.

Comment: The other problem with using netbeans is that this is a project for work, so I don't have sufficent permissions on my development machine to install it. Ideally I'd like an Ant only solution which doesn't require EITHER of netbeans or eclipse. If you're advocating using netbeans to build the Ant file, I'd go with that, but like I said, I can't install it, so simply hand editing the Ant script would be the only solution really.

Comment: Well, with Eclipse you have to duplicate all the project properties into your Ant file. Custom compiling with Eclipse is not easy either and is poorly documented. So you be ready either fully rely with Eclipse or have lots of workarounds. My current project in NetBeans is 100% integrated with the IDE, still I can run `ant build` without any IDE environment whatsoever.

Comment: As for Eclipse, the answer below will solve your immediate build time problems.

Answer (score 2):

The `javac` task in your ant build isn't referencing your third-party classes at all. To address this you'll need to specifically reference them in the classpath. The best way to handle this is to set up a `project.class.path` property, and reference that property using the `classpath` or `classpathref` attribute for the `javac` task.

Here's an example `project.class.path`. I'm making the assumption that *lib.dir* will contain your third-party jars or classes:

```
<path id="project.class.path">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
  <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
</path>
```

Alternately you can supply individual jar files specifically using more `pathelement` attributes:

```
<path id="project.class.path">
  <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/JDom2.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/AnotherSupportLibrary.jar"/>
  ...
```

Now, in your `compile` task:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
           classpath="${project.class.path}"/>
</target>
```

Now, you'll also need to include the third-party libraries in the jar that you build. The `jar` task has a provision for merging the contents of support jars into the jar being constructed, see the description under *Merging Archives* in the [documentation for the jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Also you should read the documentation and look over the examples carefully for the [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and also look over [Writing a Simple Buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html), and finally for setting up more complicated classpaths, look over the documentation for [Directory-based Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#directorybasedtasks).

Comment: I'm not using third party .jar files, they're .class files, but I'll see if this works and report back anyway. Will this recurse down the folder tree within /lib/ or will I need to set that up some other way?

Comment: @AdamHarries look over the linked documentation: ant tasks that deal with directory structures _do_ recurse as you'd expect and you'll use some combination of `includes` and `excludes` to determine which files end up being referenced. So from my first example, if you just have `<fileset dir="${lib.dir}"/>`, that will pick up everything from _lib_. Then you'll need a similar reference to _lib_ when you build the jar with the jar task.

Comment: for some reason this is giving me "Reference ${project.class.path} not found" errors. I've checked spelling matches, and added parentheses around the reference in javac, but it can't find it. Removing the "${" and "}" makes it work, but I still get the same "Cannot find symbol" errors I get without it. I also replaced the .jar with .class, as like I said in the question it's distributed with .class files.

Comment: @AdamHarries amended the answer, was missing surrounding quotes in the javac classpathref: `classpathref="${project.class.path}"/>`

Comment: ok, so I've managed to find .jar versions of the library I'm using, and got it **ALMOST** compiling. All the errors I've got to do with missing references to JDom2 and HWPF libraries have gone, but I'm now getting errors to do with Swing, and it's claiming that methods which are Overriding parent methods aren't, even though they are.

Comment: @AdamHarries another change, I was mixing up the usage of `classpath` and `classpathref` but sounds like you've gotten farther already

Comment: ha, use of classpath actually puts me back to square one for some reason...this is really annoying :/

Comment: @AdamHarries make sure that it's `classpath="${project.class.path}"`. also, kill the `includes` if you just want it to pull every class and/or jar from the _lib_ directory into the classpath.

Comment: I think I'm going to give up at this point - I can't seem to make ant do anything reasonable, and it's looking increasingly like simply writing some instructions for how to get it working with Eclipse might be a lot eaiser. Thanks for the help though!